# spring batch 3.0.3 get "updates to tables using non-transactional storage engines such as MyISAM " with mysql 5.6

Tags: spring-batch

I use spring batch 3.0.3.RELEASE in grails 2.4.4

I found exception when i execute the code below.

> "When @@GLOBAL.ENFORCE_GTID_CONSISTENCY = 1, updates to non-transactional tables can only be done in either autocommitted statements or single-statement transactions, and never in the same statement as updates to transactional tables."

the code is

```
List<Flow> flowList = Lists.newArrayList()

    Shop.findAllByCityIdAndTypeAndStatus(cityId, 1 as byte, 1 as byte).each {
        Shop stationShop ->

            TaskletStep taskletStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("copy_city_item_to_station").tasklet(new Tasklet() {
                @Override
                RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                    copyCityItemToStationItem(item, stationShop)
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED
                }
            }).build()

            Flow flow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("subflow").from(taskletStep).end();

            flowList.add(flow)
    }


    Flow splitFlow = new FlowBuilder<Flow>("split_city_item_to_station").split(eventTaskExecutor).add(flowList.toArray(new Flow[0])).build();

    FlowJobBuilder builder = jobBuilderFactory.get("push_item_to_all_station").start(splitFlow).end();

    Job job = builder.preventRestart().build()

    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("city.item.id", item.id).toJobParameters())
```

the google say the problom maybe exist in "https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-restrictions.html", so i replace all the ENGINE form MyISAM to InnoDB in file 'schema-mysql.sql', and it works.

now i want to know what i do is right or not, is there a potential bug in my way ?

Answer (score 2):

What you did is correct.  That's a bug in Spring Batch's generated SQL file for MySql.  I've created an issue in Jira that you can follow here: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2373.